SFTP connection in RUST. How to add KexAlgorithms and HostKeyAlgorithms?
I am very new at RUST and am having difficulty with the SFTP connection.
I was trying to use openssh with openssh_sftp_client. This is the code I am working on (it is just from openssh document).
use openssh::{Session, Stdio, SessionBuilder};
use openssh_sftp_client::Sftp;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let builder = SessionBuilder::default();
    let (builder, destination) = builder.resolve("ssh://username@hostname:22");
    
    let tempdir = builder.launch_master(destination).await?;

    let session = Session::new_process_mux(tempdir);
    println!("Session created");

    let mut child = session
        .subsystem("sftp")
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .await?;
    println!("Child spawned");

    Sftp::new(
        child.stdin().take().unwrap(),
        child.stdout().take().unwrap(),
        Default::default(),
    )
    .await?
    .close()
    .await?;

    Ok(())
}

However, I cannot make it work. let session = Session::new_process_mux(tempdir); part seems to be problematic. Below is the message I got when I ran the code.
Error: Connect(Custom { kind: ConnectionAborted, 
    error: "Unable to negotiate with 198.55.199.53 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. 
    Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1" })

When I accessed through Mac terminal, I used below config, and ~ $ sftp DATA easily connects to the server.
Host DATA
  HostName hostname
  User username
  KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
  HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss

I think KexAlgorithms and HostKeyAlgorithms parts are the problems I couldn't incorporate into rust code. Is there any way to deal with this?
